# How to avoid restarting Apache proxy when you restart CouchDB

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, couchdb

I'm running a localhost CouchDB instance using [CouchDBX](http://janl.github.com/couchdbx/) on my Mac, proxied behind Apache 2 using the `ProxyPass` directive:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName playlick # points to localhost in /etc/hosts
    DocumentRoot "/Users/james/Sites/playlick"
    ProxyPass /data http://localhost:5984
    ProxyPassReverse /data http://localhost:5984
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to hit my Couch instance at `http://playlick/data` while it's **not running** I get a **503 Service Temporarily Unavailable** error, as would be expected.

I then start up the Couch server and hit the same URL, but I *still* get the error until I restart the Apache proxy.

If on the other hand, I start up the Couch instance **before** hitting that URL, everything works fine without having to touch Apache.

So it seems as though the 503 error is cached until the Apache process is restarted. How do I stop this from happening?

**OR**, if that's not possible, how do I force Apache to restart when I start up the Couch instance in the CouchDBX GUI app?

Comment: How in the world did you ever get /data to work properly. I try and always get "File does not exist: [DocumentRoot]/_all_dbs, referer: https://localhost/data/_utils/index.html". It looks like there are problems in the jquery.couch.js because they refer to "/_all_dbs" and removing the "/" does make the above error appear as relative to _utils but is this really a bug or is there something else i have to configure?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe what you need to be looking at is the retry option that you can pass with the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive.

> **retry** default: 60 seconds
>
> Connection pool worker retry timeout in seconds. If the connection
>   pool worker to the backend server is
>   in the error state, Apache will not
>   forward any requests to that server
>   until the timeout expires. This
>   enables to shut down the backend
>   server for maintenance, and bring it
>   back online later. A value of 0 means
>   always retry workers in an error state
>   with no timeout.

Comment: Perfect. This did it:

    ProxyPass /data http://localhost:5984 retry=0

Comment: Also fixed the same issue for node.js apache passthrough.